# how to write functional tests in intern js on an app that has async fynctions?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, dojo, intern

I have a html page that requests for credentials once the page is loaded. Once the correct creds are submitted, an async function is executed. The async function returns a promise. Once the promise is resolved, a node is inserted into dom with response text.

```
var executeRequest = Request(req);
  executeRequest.then(function(response) {
    var node = domConstruct.toDom("<div id='text'></div>");
    domConstruct.place(node, "title", "after");
    node.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response);
  });
```

But the test is not executing completely as it is not waiting for the promise to get resolved.

```
  var dfd = this.async(15000);
  return this.remote
    .get(require.toUrl(url))
    .setFindTimeout(5000)
    .elementById('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0')
    .click()
    .type('user1')
    .end()
    .elementById('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1')
    .click()
    .type('user1')
    .end()
    .elementById('dijit_form_Button_0')
    .click()
    .end()
    .waitForElementById('text')
    .text()
    .then(dfd.rejectOnError(function(result) {
      assert.equal(result.length, 2, 'When form is submitted, operation should complete successfully');
      dfd.resolve();
    }), dfd.reject);
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be something like :

```
//ready is dojo/tests/support/ready
return ready(this.get('remote'), require.toUrl(url))
    .setFindTimeout(5000)
    .elementById('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_0')
    .click()
    .type('user1')
    .end()
    .elementById('dijit_form_ValidationTextBox_1')
    .click()
    .type('user1')
    .end()
    .elementById('dijit_form_Button_0')
    .click()
    .end()
    .waitForElementById('text')
    .text()
    .then(function (result) {
        assert.equal(result, 'loaded');
    });
```

Comment: no ben, it didnt work. It is skipping to the next test exactly when the promise is returned by the async `request` method. I guess, i am handling that part in a wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

When `this.remote.get(...)` is called, the WebDriver server waits for the synchronous parts (images, script tags, etc.) of the target page to load and then moves on. If your page includes asynchronous startup code, you'll have to add something to your test to wait for it to complete. Since you know the ID of an element that will be added to the page, just use a `findById` to wait for it:

```
return this.remote
    // Load the page
    .get(require.toUrl(url))

    // Make the find timeout long enough that your Promise should have 
    // completed
    .setFindTimeout(5000)

    // Start looking for the element that should be added; Intern will keep
    // looking for up to findtimeout ms
    .findElementById('text')
    .end()

    // At this point the element is in place, so the promise resolved
    // rest of test
```